How to Properly Separate Flutter Assets by Density to Reduce App Size?
I have followed the steps for implementing resolution-aware image assets as described in Flutter's best practices. However, after building the AAB and uploading it to the Play Store, the download size of the app has significantly increased due to the newly included assets. This is not the expected behavior.
Here's what I have done:

Placed the images in the assets/images/1.0x, assets/images/2.0x, and assets/images/3.0x directories.
Correctly referenced the assets in pubspec.yaml.
Configured build.gradle to enable density and ABI splits.

Despite this setup, the app size on the Play Store is larger than expected. What might I be missing, or what else can I do to ensure that the Play Store serves only the necessary assets for each device, effectively reducing the download size?
Additionally, could you confirm from which version of Flutter the resolution-aware image assets feature started supporting app size reduction in the Play Store?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Does this answer your question? How to add/manage multiple image size/resolution in flutter assets

@Abdulaziz - Yes, I have implemented the steps as described in the article, but it is not working as expected. The problem is that the download size of the AAB on the Play Store has significantly increased due to the newly included assets, which should not be the case.

OK, maybe renaming from 1.0x to 1.5x and adding 4.0x to fullfill the mapping structure helps. Also you have to let main asset alive as it is the base scaling point

Wondering if you manage to force Google Play and AppStore to optimize the download size this way?
